# Can I enable JavaScript for my website visitors?

Tags: javascript, html, browser

Is there any possible way to tell a browser to enable JavaScript via HTML or HTML5? Like firebug does it :
[image]
When You click on enable JavaScript and refresh link, the JavaScript is Enabled and page is refreshed.

Comment: I hope not, and I can't imagine browsers supporting such a feature: when a user has disabled JavaScript they don't want you going behind their back to re-enable it.

Comment: Normally, no. And for a good reason. But bugs like https://plus.google.com/111993737823468994589/posts/5iMF51GcMtM do happen.

Comment: @DCoder. Should be mention it's A BUG.

Comment: Most users have javascript enabled these days, and let's face it, those who don't must be having a hell of a time with a large portion of the web.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no way, Just think of the security problems this kind of "feature" create.

Firebug is part of the browser and not a content.

Comment: That feature is coming right after the "send all credit card numbers" feature. Really looking forward to it.